# 1993 Cavalier 2.2 misfiring

Tags: misfire, cavalier

My 1993 Cavalier 2.2 is misfiring on the #3 cylinder. A check of the spark plug showed a dry plug but still had spark. Ceramic was cracked so I replaced all four. Thinking the injector was bad, I replaced it as well. Also replaced the fuel filter. Pulled the codes with the jumper wire and have a 12,23,24 and 33.  Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried clearing the codes to see what comes back? 12 = No distributor reference pulse; 23 = Intake air temp sensor error; 24 = Vehicle speed sensor error; 33 = MAP sensor circuit error

Comment: There's no way to tell if those codes are current or historic. If you car is running better now clear the codes and drive for awhile, then check the codes again. If there's no codes you're probably good, if the codes come back then it's time to troubleshoot.